# cannot get SLF4J working with glassfish 4

Tags: slf4j, glassfish-4, glassfish-embedded

I have configured glassfish 3 to use SLF4J in the past by using the SLF4J JUL bridge and it worked fine.  The problem I'm having now is that if I use my same setup, SLF4J complains about there being duplicate SLF4J bindings on the classpath and after searching, glassfish itself contains those reference.

How do I get SLF4J working?  I tried making my dependency upon the SLF4J-API as provided, and then removed LogBack Classic since glassfish already contains some logback code.  Doing those things doesn't yield any successful results.

Walter

Comment: Can you please add some details about the error messages you get?

Comment: When I configure glassfish to use SLF4J, all my messages are gone essentially, no error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may helps you

Download [Glassfish 4](https://glassfish.java.net/download.html), [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/download.html) and [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/download.html)

Stop gf4

```
$GF_INSTALL\bin>asadmin stop-domain
```

and then

Copy

> - jul-to-slf4j-1.7.5
> - slf4j-api-1.7.5
> - logback-core-1.0.13
> - logback-classic-1.0.13

to

> $GF_INSTALL/glassfish/lib/endorsed

Create logback.xml in

> $GF_INSTALL/glassfish/domains/domain1/config

containing

```
<configuration debug="true" scan="true">
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>/tmp/gf_server.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{52} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Modify

> $GF_INSTALL/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/logging.properties

and replace

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
handlerServices=com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.formatter=com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.file=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/logs/server.log
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.rotationTimelimitInMinutes=0
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.flushFrequency=1
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=50000
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.logtoConsole=false
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.rotationLimitInBytes=2000000
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.excludeFields=
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.multiLineMode=true
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.SyslogHandler.useSystemLogging=false
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count=1
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.retainErrorsStasticsForHours=0
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.validator.util.Version=warn
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.maxHistoryFiles=0
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.rotationOnDateChange=false
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=%h/java%u.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.XMLFormatter
```

with

```
handlers=org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler
handlerServices=com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.formatter=com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.file=/tmp/server.log
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.rotationTimelimitInMinutes=0
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.flushFrequency=1
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=50000
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.logtoConsole=false
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.rotationLimitInBytes=2000000
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.excludeFields=
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.multiLineMode=true
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.SyslogHandler.useSystemLogging=false
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count=1
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.retainErrorsStasticsForHours=0
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.validator.util.Version=warn
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.maxHistoryFiles=0
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.rotationOnDateChange=false
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=%h/java%u.log
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.formatter=com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.alarms=false
```

Add this two new JVM options to

> domain->configs->config->java-config

in

> $GF_INSTALL/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml

```
<jvm-options>-Djava.util.logging.config.file=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/logging.properties</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Dlogback.configurationFile=file:///${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/logback.xml</jvm-options>
```

then start gf4 again

> $GF_INSTALL\bin>asadmin start-domain

Comment: Part of that looks similar to what I already did, I hope to try this within the next 2 days and report back.  Thanks,

Comment: You are welcome, Walter, it works as expected for me in a clean gf4.

Comment: At first glance, it appears to be working; however, I only tried a subset of those things: the important one I already had (SLF4JBridgeHandler), I updated java.util.logging.config.file and logback.configurationFile to a locally provided one.  I noticed even though my configuration says DEBUG for the root level, it only logs INFO or higher.

Comment: Also, I am using the maven glassfish plugin, so it is slightly different.

Comment: @WalterWhite did you manage to fix the problem with logging only being of the level INFO or higher? I am experiencing the same problem with embedded glassfish.

Comment: No, I am still having to use loglevel of INFO or higher just to see my logs statements.  I play with this off-and-on to see what I can do to get this working.  I'm planning to migrate to either a managed or remote instance of glassfish as embedded glassfish is quick ... but it has limitations.

Comment: Instead of this enabling SLF4J logging, it seems to disable *all* logging in GlassFish 4. And that's regardless of the logging level I set in logback.xml.

Answer (score 1):

If someone else having trouble with configured `ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender`, i might have a solution for you.

The problem is, that following the instructions of @vzamanillo, logback itself is initialized twice. This is caused by classloader isolation of GlassFish (one time by main ClassLoader, one time by EAR ClassLoader). It becomes visible, if u configure logback with `debug=true`. If a `RollingFileAppender` is used now, two OutputStreams were opened on the same configured logfile. This prevents the logfile to be removed during rollover (visible in debug mode).

To fix this issue, i moved the libraries from `/modules/endorsed` to  `/domains/domain1/lib/ext`. Now GlassFish 4 (concrete Payara) initializes logback only once and everything works as expected.

By the way: to replace JUL logging, specifying `<contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator" />` is a MUST, otherwise you are facing big performance issues.

To dispatch also the loggings of potential 3rd party libs to SLF4j, don't forget to install the dispatcher jars as well, which are i.e.:

- jcl-over-slf4j.jar
- jul-to-slf4j.jar
- log4j-over-slf4j.jar