# Logback RollingFileAdapter does not work as expected in Payara Server

Tags: java, logback, glassfish-4, payara

I already did search over stackoverflow and google it alot, but my problem is not solved yet.

Problem:

In code I have these loggers:

```
@Stateless
public class NotificatrionService implements INotificationService {
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("DEF");
    private final static Logger logger_wsdlr = LoggerFactory.getLogger("wsdlr");
:
:
}
```

And under certain cases I use each one

```
:
logger_wsdlr.info("Some info messages");
:
logger.debug("Some debug messages"));
:
```

To setup logback with `Payara Server 4` (stable Glassfish 4), follow instructions wrote by @vzamanillo at this post:

[cannot get SLF4J working with glassfish 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20607837/1223901)

At that guide (or other found) people use `ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender`. With this appender logback works pretty well, but I need to rotate log files. Then I just setup `ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender` in my `logback.xml`, just like this:

```
<configuration scan="true" debug="true">
    <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
        <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
    </contextListener>
    <property name="pattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level][%thread][%logger{36}]%msg%n"/>
    <property name="dir" value="/tmp/log"/>
    <appender name="DEF" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/logs/my_def.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>${pattern}</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="WSDLR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${dir}/dt_wsdlr.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${dir}/dt_wsdlr-%d{yyyy.MM.dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>90</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>3GB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <Pattern>${pattern}</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <!-- appender that replace payara default server.log, defualt was redirected to ${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/tmp/server.log -->
    <appender name="GF" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/logs/server.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
        </filter>

        <encoder>
            <Pattern>${pattern}</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="GF"/>
    </root>

    <logger level="TRACE" name="DEF" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>
    <logger level="DEBUG" name="wsdlr" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="WSDLR"/>
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

When I used `RollingFileAppender` reference in my code, **the file associated to the appender simply did not have been created and logs just missing**.

---

I try to apply steps from the post referred above (@casten [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42514987/1223901)) but just a new error raised

```
2017-04-07 10:49:25.297 [ERROR][Thread-20][j.e.system.tools.deployment.common]Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:353)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:501)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:406)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.load(InstallerThread.java:211)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.run(InstallerThread.java:100)
2017-04-07 10:49:25.297 [ERROR][Thread-20][javax.enterprise.system.core]Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:353)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:501)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:406)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.load(InstallerThread.java:211)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.run(InstallerThread.java:100)
```

I just rollback the jars location.

Can anyone help me to find the right way to use `RollingFileAppender`?

---

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shame on me... my problem was a typo ....

```
<appender name="WSDLR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${dir}/dt_wsdlr.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${dir}/dt_wsdlr-%d{yyyy.MM.dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>90</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>3GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
        <Pattern>${pattern}</Pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

the correct class reference is `ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender` instead of `ch.qos.logback.core.RollingFileAppender`.

Comment: Please mark as the correct answer (even if it's yours) to indicate the problem was solved.

Comment: sorry, I was deleted the post, but ... still alive.